# Binding multiple list items on post in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

I would like to bind a form that has multiple list items on post and below is my code:

```
   <form asp-page-handler="InsertAssignedStates" method="post">
           name="assignedStates" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
                        <div class="well text-right">
                            <select asp-for="Stest"
                                    multiple="multiple"
                                    size="10"
                                    class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 ml-sm-3 leftList"
                                    id="assignedStateList"
                                    asp-items="@Model.AssignedTaxStateList">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And I have this in the page model:

```
 [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
 public IList<Tax> AssignedTaxStates { get; set; }
 public IActionResult OnPostInsertAssignedStates()
    {
  
     return Redirect("Index/");
    }
```

It hits the breakpoint but not is bound.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net core bind data with name attribute.Here is a demo to bind inputs with list and bind multiple select with list in razor pages.

Model:

```
public class Tax
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

cshtml:

```
<form asp-page-handler="InsertAssignedStates" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
            <div class="well text-right">
                <select asp-for="Stest"
                        multiple="multiple"
                        size="10"
                        class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 ml-sm-3 leftList"
                        id="assignedStateList"
                        asp-items="@Model.AssignedTaxStateList">
                </select>
            </div>
            @{ var i = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model.AssignedTaxStates)
            { 
                <div class="well text-right">
                    <input value="@item.Id"  name="AssignedTaxStates[@i].Id"/>
                    <input value="@item.Name" name="AssignedTaxStates[@i].Name"/>

                </div>
                i++;
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<SelectListItem> AssignedTaxStateList { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public IList<Tax> AssignedTaxStates { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<string> Stest { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            AssignedTaxStateList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" } };
            AssignedTaxStates = new List<Tax> { new Tax { Id = 1, Name = "tax1" }, new Tax { Id = 2, Name = "tax2" }, new Tax { Id = 3, Name = "tax3" } };
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostInsertAssignedStates()
        {

            return Redirect("Index/");
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: What date are you referring to?

Comment: Oh,it's my mistake,I mean data.